# Validations, Nested Attributes and error handling when parent model isn't valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Recently I added validations to one of the models in my application, and this seems to have caused a somewhat strange behaviour that I'm not handling properly in my code.

Here's a hypothetical example:

**Clients**

```
# name: string, phone: string, address: string

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :transactions
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :transaction, allow_destroy: true

    validate :phone, numericality: true
end
```

**Transactions**

```
# p_date: date, location_id: integer

class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end
```

This is how the controller would look like (again, have in mind that this is hypothetical):

**PurchasesController**

```
before_action :set_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @client.update(client_params)
      format.html { redirect_to clients_path, notice: 'Updated Succesfully' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @client }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end


def client_params
    params.require(:client).permit(
        :name, :phone, :address,
        transaction_attributes: [:id, :p_date, :location_id, :_destroy]
    )
end

def set_client
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
end
```

For new records this works fine, but when I run into old ones that do not conform to the new validation rules in the phone number, the nested attributes aren't saved, because it's parent record is no longer valid.

I'm trying to find a way how to handle such errors.

Currently, this would be handled by the `else` condition in `if @client.update(client_params)` in the controller. When an error happens, the controller renders the `:edit` action, which results in another error in my view, cause now the helper that generates the fields for the nested form is receiving a null value for @client.

The `view` in question that generates the error looks like this:

**purchases/:client_id/edit.html.haml**

```
= form_for @client, :url => {:controller => 'purchase', :action => 'update'} do |f|
  - if @client.errors.any?
    #error_explanation
      %h2
        The following errors were found:
      %ul
        - @client.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
          %li= message
  =render 'form', f: f
  .actions
    =f.submit 'Save Changes', :class => 'btn btn-md btn-primary'
```

The error says: "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty", which I'm assuming it is cause the render is not sending the id of the Client.

In case you're wondering, I'm using `form_for @client, :url => {:controller => 'purchase', :action => 'update'} do |f|` cause this view is not in the Client controller. if I omit the extra parameters, the form is sent directly to the Client controller, which has different code pertaining only to the Client model.

I've partially managed to work around this by using the following in the update action:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @client.update(client_params)
      # *snip*
    else
      format.html { redirect_to edit_purchase_path(@client) }
      format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This will redirect me back to the edit action, but no errors are printed. I get an identical page with the values used before I edited the values of the Transaction. I'm think there must be an easy way to send the errors back to the view, but I'm not sure where are these supposed to be used.

The "original" controller was generated by a scaffold, so the `render :edit` part is from the scaffolding itself. I'm aware my example could be somewhat vague (I'm just transcribing what I'm experiencing), so bear with me if this sounds a little odd. I'll gladly go into more detail if the information provided isn't enough.

Comment: Run `rake routes` and make sure the client id parameter key matches what the route is expecting (i.e. `params[:id]` vs. `params[:client_id]`). Your `set_client` before_action in PurchasesController is expecting `params[:id]` for the client.

Comment: I'm afraid that bit may have been a bit confusing, as I put it there to show what I was expecting to receive (:client_id). The controller does have :id as its expected parameter, and the routes are the standard ones generated by the scaffolding.